# Find Facebook posts liked by friendlist members

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-search, facebook-search

Can I search Facebook for posts that were liked only by members of a friends list that I created?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Facebook Graph Search was retired.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You will need to manually add specified friends to a search query.

For example,

`Posts liked by Boz or liked by Mark Zuckerberg`

https://www.facebook.com/search/4/stories-liked/1681/stories-liked/union

Comment: The link is broken.